# java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long

Tags: java, ant

I'm trying to build a project using ant and it gives above exception and faild to build. What is the solution to this problem. Here is the build.xml compile target that i'm running

```
<property name="cep.home" value="../../.."/>
<property name="src.dir" value="src"/>
<property name="temp.dir" value="temp"/>
<property name="lib.dir" value="../../lib"/>
<property name="class.dir" value="${temp.dir}/classes"/>



<path id="javac.classpath">
    <pathelement path="${class.dir}"/>
    <fileset dir="${cep.home}/repository/components/plugins/">

    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="clean">
    <echo>Test</echo>
    <!--<delete dir="target" quiet="true"/>-->
    <delete dir="${class.dir}" quiet="true"/>
    <delete dir="${temp.dir}"/>
</target>

<target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="${temp.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${class.dir}"/>
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="init">
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${class.dir}">
        <include name="*/**"/>
        <classpath refid="javac.classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="run" depends="compile">
    <java classname="com.client.Main"
          classpathref="javac.classpath" fork="true">

    </java>
</target>
```

Comment: How are you defining the reference `javac.classpath`?

Comment: I updated the question with whole build file